# What's wrong with the usage of to_date in this Oracle query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (date1, date2) 
VALUES (to_date('2012-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2012-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

but I get:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
```

and:

```
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

but my usage of `to_date` seems okay?

Many thanks.

Comment: This should be working, see this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e75a8/1).  Is this the only query that you are attempting to run?  what is the datatype of `date1` and `date2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks correct.  And it works for me so there must be something else to the problem that isn't part of your example...

```
SQL> create table some_table( date1 date, date2 date );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO some_table (date1, date2)
  2  VALUES (to_date('2012-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2012-10-24','YYYY-MM-DD'));

1 row created.
```

Are you really using hard-coded literals?  Or are the strings you're passing to `to_date` coming from a table?  Is it possible that there is (at least) one row in the table where the data doesn't match the expected format.  Note that a row that is ultimately filtered out by a `WHERE` clause, even a `WHERE` clause in a subquery, can still call `to_date` before getting filtered out and cause the error.  So it would be perfectly plausible that you would have something like

```
INSERT INTO some_table( date1, date2 )
  SELECT to_date( string1, 'YYYY-MM-DD' ), to_date( string2, 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM some_other_table
           WHERE condition_that_limits_the_data_to_just_valid_date_strings )
   WHERE some_other_condition
```

return an error.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tips Justin.  The values are coming from a (PHP) program.  I do have other (non-date) fields in the DB.. I will take a look an experiment.